# update vaadin grid when new record added to database

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to add the element to the table in the database and update the grid with new data (probably I should add records directly on UI to the table but whatever).

My `grid` component looks like this

```
@SpringComponent
public class PlayersGrid extends Grid<Player> {

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterInit() {
        addColumn(Player::getId).setHeader("ID");
        addColumn(Player::getName).setHeader("Name");
        addColumn(Player::getCharacterClass).setHeader("Class");
        addColumn(Player::getLevel).setHeader("Level");
    }

    public class GridContentObserver implements ContentObserver {

        @Override
        public void refreshContent() {
            PlayersGrid.this.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I add `players` via form that looks like this

```
@SpringComponent
public class CharacterCreationForm extends FormLayout {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CharacterCreationForm.class);

    private List<ContentObserver> boundObservers = new ArrayList<>();

    private TextField name;
    private TextField characterClass;
    private TextField level;

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository repository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void create() {
        name = new TextField();
        characterClass = new TextField();
        level = new TextField();

        addFormItem(name, "Name");
        addFormItem(characterClass, "Class");
        addFormItem(level, "Level");

        Binder<Player> binder = new Binder<>(Player.class);

        binder
            .forField(level)
            .withConverter(new StringToIntegerConverter(0, ""))
            .bind(Player::getLevel, Player::setLevel);

        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

        Button button = new Button("Save");
        button.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
            try {
                Player newPlayer = new Player();
                binder.writeBean(newPlayer);
                LOGGER.info("Attempt to write object: {}", newPlayer);

                repository.save(newPlayer);
                // notify observers
                boundObservers.forEach(ContentObserver::refreshContent);
            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        add(button);
    }

    public void addObserver(ContentObserver observer) {
        boundObservers.add(observer);
    }

}
```

My main view in the application looks like this

```
public MainView(PlayerRepository repository, PlayersGrid grid, CharacterCreationForm form) {
    form.addObserver(grid.new GridContentObserver());
    form.setWidth("30%");

    // find the way to set items in the component
    grid.setItems(repository.findAll());

    HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    horizontalLayout.add(form);

    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    verticalLayout.add(grid, form);
    verticalLayout.setHeight("100%");
    add(verticalLayout);

    setClassName("main-layout");
}
```

On startup I have all my stored players in the grid. But when I save new ones using form it adds new records in the database, but doesn't update the grid.

What is wrong?

Comment: since GridContentObserver work in relevance to the "this" object, how did you bind PlayersGrid instance to the GridContentObserver ? :)

Comment: @nabeel I passed it as `grid.new GridContentObserver` no? Or what do you mean?

Comment: For me it looks like that you are saving new entries to database yes, but do not update the content of the data provider, hence changes are not reflected in Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below changes that i think would make the code more clear and solve the issue with the ContentObserver

(didn't run the code so i'm not sure about compilation problems!)

change 1: PlayersGrid implements ContentObserver instead of having inner class

```
@SpringComponent
public class PlayersGrid extends Grid<Player> implements ContentObserver {

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterInit() {
        addColumn(Player::getId).setHeader("ID");
        addColumn(Player::getName).setHeader("Name");
        addColumn(Player::getCharacterClass).setHeader("Class");
        addColumn(Player::getLevel).setHeader("Level");
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshContent() {
        this.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
    }
}
```

change 2: boundObservers.forEach

```
@SpringComponent
public class CharacterCreationForm extends FormLayout {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(CharacterCreationForm.class);

    private List<ContentObserver> boundObservers = new ArrayList<>();

    private TextField name;
    private TextField characterClass;
    private TextField level;

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository repository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void create() {
        name = new TextField();
        characterClass = new TextField();
        level = new TextField();

        addFormItem(name, "Name");
        addFormItem(characterClass, "Class");
        addFormItem(level, "Level");

        Binder<Player> binder = new Binder<>(Player.class);

        binder
            .forField(level)
            .withConverter(new StringToIntegerConverter(0, ""))
            .bind(Player::getLevel, Player::setLevel);

        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

        Button button = new Button("Save");
        button.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
            try {
                Player newPlayer = new Player();
                binder.writeBean(newPlayer);
                LOGGER.info("Attempt to write object: {}", newPlayer);

                repository.save(newPlayer);
                // notify observers

                // updated
                boundObservers.forEach( observer -> observer.refreshContent() );

            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        add(button);
    }

    public void addObserver(ContentObserver observer) {
        boundObservers.add(observer);
    }

}
```

change 3:  grid is now also the ContentObserver, so its easier to manage and understand.

```
public MainView(PlayerRepository repository, PlayersGrid grid, CharacterCreationForm form) {
    // updated
    form.addObserver(grid);
    form.setWidth("30%");

    // find the way to set items in the component
    grid.setItems(repository.findAll());

    HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    horizontalLayout.add(form);

    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    verticalLayout.add(grid, form);
    verticalLayout.setHeight("100%");
    add(verticalLayout);

    setClassName("main-layout");
}
```

Comment: I never used this approach: this.getDataProvider() i prefer to pass the repository to the listener and run grid.setItems(repository.findAll())

Comment: did you try to debug and make sure that refreshContent method is called ?

Comment: yes. It invokes the method but it doesn't update the table

Comment: It seems the issue is similar to this https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17008011 but the approach with `keymapper` doesn't work for me either

Comment: decided just to `setItems` in the observer method

Comment: you might need to remove all before the setItems