# Method for reload the UI or page and downoald the changes of data base (Vaadin and java)

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm using vaadin 8 and I want reload o refresh a page of my app after click a button and donwload the changes from data base for could use some new parameters.

¿Could someone help me?,
Thanks

Comment: what do you have so far ?

Comment: I have implemented all the code, I only need a method who could reload o refresh a page of my app and could load the information when I initiate session for example because after I initiate session I have to reload the page with F5 for could load the parameters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686153/update-vaadin-grid-when-new-record-added-to-database/51689263?noredirect=1#comment90352163_51689263

Answer (score 0):

Separate layouting the components and loading data into the components into two different steps. Ie. constructor of the view only adds layout and components and configures them correctly, and a separate controller or method calls the backend and plugs in the correct data. If you want to refresh the view, you can call the "load data" part again and the view will be updated, while maintaining the component structure.